# appSettings.config file transformations not applied using msbuild

Tags: web-config, web-config-transform

I have inherited a project which has the appSettings and Connectionstrings in separate files.Using SlowCheetah I generated the transforms for each file for each environment.

The structure looks something like the following
`appSettings.config`
 `appSettings.DEV.config`
 `appSettings.UAT.config` 
 `appSettings.RELEASE.config`

`connectionStrings.config`
 `connectionStrings.DEV.config`
 `connectionStrings.UAT.config` 
 `connectionStrings.RELEASE.config`

I tested the transforms locally using the publish feature in visual studio 2010. All good. However when I create a build definition in TFS and automate the deployment via msbuild the transformations are not applied. The release appsettings file for example contains the contents of the base file. No transforms are applied. I was wondering if anyone else had tried this and if they experienced the same issues. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi,
   After a little more research I found what i was looking for. The following link explains the steps in detail.

http://sedodream.com/2011/12/12/SlowCheetahXMLTransformsFromACIServer.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your Build Definition you probably defined the Configurations to use. Part of that also defines something like Any CPU or x86. As it turns out the solution the Platform Any CPU has a space where in the project files the Platform AnyCPU does not have a space.

I found the best way to get around this was to leave the Platform blank and only put in the configuration name. VS will pop up a warning letting you know that there is data missing, you can just hit Yes to save it anyways. Alternatively you can just type in your configurations like the following |Release,|Debug.

The pattern is [PlatformName]|[ConfigurationName],[PlatformName]|[ConfigurationName],...